# Collapse all expanded sidebar folders in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a menu option or keyboard shortcut to collapse all expanded folders in the sidebar? It gets messy over there and seems like there should be a better way than closing them one by one.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

On OSX: <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd> at the **root node**.

On windows/linux: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd>

Comment: In Sublime Text 3 it's alt + left click

Comment: would really like a keyboard shortcut to close ALL folders

Comment: @Jordy : You saved a mess.

Comment: @autopoietic I'm all for not leaving the keyboard (I use VIM mode) but don't you need to use the mouse to interact with the sidebar anyway?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter ctrl+0 focuses the sidebar, allowing cursor up/down to select/preview files (or cmd+up to get to the top), but I haven't found a shortcut to collapse

Comment: @autopoietic Yep, you're right! Thanks for that tip!

Comment: Is there a way to change this keybind?

Comment: Keybindings can be edited in the config file. Open the quick panel and search for 'Preferences: Key Bindings'.

Comment: @jnns I'm not sure this is a keybind, as mouse actions don't seem to appear in the .sublime-keymap file.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a relevant [command](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/sublime-text-2/reference/commands.html) so guess it's not possible to customise this.

Comment: @DavidCook It seems you're right. The `.sublime-mousemap` file doesn't have anything on this either and running `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the console doesn't show a command being run when sidebar folders are collapsed/expanded, either.

Answer (score 21):

For Sublime Text 3 on Linux Mint 17.2 w/ Cinnamon I had to disable the following setting:

System Settings->Windows->Behavior->Moving and Resizing Windows->Special key to move and resize windows

After that Alt+left click worked!

Comment: And for those using compiz: CompizConfig Settings Manager -> Window Management -> Move Window -> click the Alt<Button1> button and disable it.
Edit: disable actually seems to not be saved, try adding an unused complex combination as a fake disable.

Comment: Also for Mint 17.3 w/ MATE (the setting is found in [start] -> Preferences -> Window)

Comment: Worked in xfce4 too. Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility(tab) -> **key used to grab and move windows property** set to **None**.

Answer (score 3):

In Sublime **Text 4**, pressing "option/alt" on your keyboard and clicking a folder in Sublime's sidebar with your mouse, will collapse all sub-folders within the folder you clicked. I'm using a Mac. I'm not sure what happens on other operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

#### Keyboard only

To collapse all expanded folders in the sidebar on macOS:

1. `ctrl + 0`: **Focus the sidebar**
2. `home` or `cmd + up`: **Select first root folder**
3. `ctrl + left`: **Collapse all sub-folders** (confusingly, not `alt` as per the equivalent mouse action).
4. (optional) `right`: Expand just the top level folder.

Thanks to the existing responses that provided this info.

I've not tested on other platforms, please update the answer if you can.

Answer (score -1):

using purely keyboard, on a mac, to unfold

```
CMD + K + 0
```

to fold, depending on the level of indentation

```
CMD + K + {level of indentation number} (eg. CMD + K + 2)
```

Refer [here](http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-code-folding/) for more details functions of sublime text. Found this really helpful

Comment: CTRL + K + {level} works on Windows for Sublime Text 3.

Comment: This answers the question how to expand and collapse code in the main editor window, not how to collapse and expand folders in the sidebar.